# VS 2010 Error Generating Unit Tests

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I have one .NET 4 DLL for which I'm having trouble generating unit tests.  I'm using VS 2010 Standard.  Every other project in the solution will generate unit test stubs for classes just fine.  For the other assemblies, I can go into the existing code, right click the class name, and select "Create Unit Tests".  I get the selection window that follows just fine.

The one assembly that I really need to get some coverage on won't generate the test stubs using the same methodology mentioned above.  I go to a class in the project/assembly, right click, select "Generate Unit Tests", and I'm met with the following error:

> Unit Test Generation Error:  The follow error was encountered while reading module 'xx.Core':  Could not resolve type reference:  [System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx]System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary

As far as I can tell, there are no direct references in the project to the framework 2.0 version of System.Web mentioned in the error message.  Searching the directory that contains the project and .CS files with a tool called grepWIN to see if the text for that reference exists in any files yields zero results.  Is it even possible to reference both the 2.0 and 4.0 version of the system.web dll at the same time, and if so, why would you want to do that?

Any ideas on how to get rid of this error message so that I can properly stub out some unit tests?

Comment: I have the same experience but sadly no answer :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, with the ObservableCollection.

My "solution" was to upgrade all referenced projects and their referenced projects to .NET 4.0. Then it worked.... However this seems a bit odd and I could well have done something else that caused the problem to disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problem with one of my projects. The problem was that after I had built my library I renamed the dll file. My project referencing the dll still built fine, however I received a similar error while generating unit tests until I renamed the dll back to its original name when it had been built.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NUNIT for unit test? If so, by default Nunit points to .Net 2.0. You need to make appropriate changes to the nunit.exe.config file.

Could you please, in Windows Explorer, navigate to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework. There you will see a number of folders with names of this kind:  v1.0.xxxxx, v1.1.xxxxx, ..., v4.0.xxxxx.  Write down the exact name of the v4.0.xxxxx folder.

With a text editor open up the file nunit.exe.config, which is in this folder: C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.2\bin\net-2.0.

Under  add:

```
<startup>  <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.xxxxx" />  </startup>
```

[*replace xxxxx by the correct numbers that you wrote down*]

and under  add:

```
<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
```

The above change worked for me. Hopefully for other people who are facing this problem.

Comment: OP is using test generation capability.  VS2010 ought to create stubs for unit tests, along with file, class, and all other plumbing.  You're talking about adding a class so that unit tests could be implemented with NUnit Framework.